# open form, save and close instantly in access

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to set up a form so that when i fill in an ID field in one form, it will save the record in another form instantly.

if it opened saved and closed discreetly that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have code behind the 2nd form, you can reference it from VBA code like:

`Form_MyFormName.Visible = False`

This line will create an instance of the form that is invisible that you can then use to perform whatever task you need.  Then close the form like:

`DoCmd.Close AcForm, "MyFormName"`

Comment: In my opinion, why not simply write the underlying records directly without having to open the form?  You can create a recordset object to open the desired table, then execute the Recordset.AddNew method to add a record, fill it in, and use Recordset.Update to save the record.  No need to mess around with opening the form, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a better option - why open the form, deal with all the form events when you don't have to.  Since your already in VBA making changes with code, why not make all the changes you need there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this - every object in Access can be referred to in code, so you'd use the form's name in VBA to call it, perform the change(s) necessary as they relate to the original form, call for a save of the called form, then a close.  Of course, if the primary form relies on data you could have changed in the secondary form - you will need to call for a save of the primary form before and after the change in the secondary form.

Sorry about the generic answer, you really didn't give us much to work with in terms of form names, field names, or the like.  But the concept should be sound.